# Expression.Call - Calling linq extension: FirstOrDefault, Where

Tags: c#, linq, expression, dynamic, predicate

I am trying to create the following dynamically, however I am having problems calling the extension method `FirstOrDefault`:

```
 using(var context = new Entities())
 {
     var list = context.Engines.Include("Cars").Select(e => e.Cars.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
 }
```

I have the following

```
Expression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Engine), "e");
Expression property = Expression.Property(parameter, "Cars");
```

- parameter = `{e}`
- property = `{e.Cars}`

Those are good, but I am encountering a problem when I try and call the `FirstOrDefault` method:

```
var result = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "FirstOrDefault", new type[] { typeof(Car)}, property);
```

I would like to get

- result = `{e.Cars.FirstOrDefault()}`

but I am getting an `InvalidOperationException`

> No generic method 'FirstOrDefault' on
>   type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is
>   compatible with the supplied type
>   arguments and arguments. No type
>   arguments should be provided if the
>   method is non-generic.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify? FirstOrDefault isn't *usually* part of the lambda, so doesn't need to be involved with Expression

Comment: My goal is to create a lambda inside a lamda, so something like this:

.Where(e => e.Cars.Where(c => c.Name == "Honda").Count > 0)

Does that clarify anything or am I confused?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you sure `e.Cars` is an [IQueryable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx)?

If not, you can't pass it to [Queryable.FirstOrDefault<T>(IQueryable<T>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301896.aspx).

If it's an [IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), change your code to call [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<T>(IEnumerable<T>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx):

```
 var result =
     Expression.Call(
         typeof(Enumerable),
         "FirstOrDefault",
         new Type[] { TypeSystem.GetElementType(property.Type) },
         property);
```

Comment: Thanks it works now. Do you know if there is a way to get the Car Type from the property expression?

Comment: @Aducci: [TypeSystem.GetElementType](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/30/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i.aspx) ( [property.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.type.aspx) )

Comment: e.Cars.AsQueryable() was another solution I think

Comment: What is TypeSystem? Uknown type.